# Is cross-device or cross-browswer testing part of functional testing?

Tags: mobile, functional, cross-browser-testing

Let's say you're ready to start testing your functional requirements.

Is it appropriate to do cross browser/device testing for each functional requirement?

Comment: Hi 8protons : I don't think your question can be answered except in the context of specific functional requirements, for a particular piece of software, in a particular development effort. It _might_ be useful to do cross-browser/device testing for every functional requirement, or it _might not_ - it depends on what you're testing and how long you have to do it and how browser-sensitive the function is and what kind of browsers/devices your user base have, and many other factors. There can be no one true answer here.

Comment: @VinceBowdren That makes complete sense and I appreciate you taking the time to thoroughly explain. I'll flag this for closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your specific requirements:

### Do your requirements demand cross browser / device testing?

- Some functional requirements do demand cross browser / device testing, e.g. an application needs to be logged in / out properly on all of its platforms.
- Some functional requirements do not demand cross browser / device testing, e.g. a legal claim link that will pop out after you click it (a very lame example)

### Which browsers are you thinking of?

- There are so many browsers / devices out there, you can not test all of them. Your application may specify a preferred browser / device, you can focus your testing effort on it.

### Do you have enough time to do it?

- Ideally, the more browser / devices you test, the better test coverage will be. But it all comes down to its time box, do you have enough time to finish all of them? You can check with your stakeholders / business owner to verify time constraint.

Comment: Thank you for this answer; it acknowledges my question well.